# How to deal with apostophe

Tags: obiee

I am trying to create the calculation below using a the filter function, however, I get a syntax error because of the Bachelor's, my question  is how can I fix the issue with Bachelor's without fixing data in the warehouse?

```
FILTER("Fact - Count"."# of Applications" USING (("Candidate
Education"."Highest Level Education" IN('Bachelor's Degree', 'Higher
Degree'))   AND ("Candidate Education"."Graduated" = 'Yes')))
```

Comment: _"I get a syntax error"_ Where is it, then?

Comment: The error is caused by  Bachelor's, in my code I have it as ('Bachelor's Degree')  but OBIEE doesn't recognize Bachelor's, it works if I make it just Bachelors, but that's not how the source data looks like.

Comment: I changed it to "Bachelor's' Degree"  if that's what you meant but its still not working. for the record I am doing this in OBIEE analysis.

Comment: You commented on the question, not the answer. And no, that's not what Chris meant; to escape a single quote, write 2 in a row: `Bachelor''s`. There is not actually any issue here, except maybe a lack of attention to reading syntax documentation before posting. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape it. '' double single quote

Comment: I formatted the code as follows but still getting a syntax error is there something else i am missing.FILTER("Fact - Count"."# of Applications" USING (("Candidate
Education"."Highest Level Education" IN('Bachelor''s Degree', 'Higher
Degree'))   AND ("Candidate Education"."Graduated" = 'Yes')))

Comment: Thanks it was an error on  my part with my syntax, should have got it right from your first response.